# Firebase Google Login

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

Firebase deprecated FirebaseSimpleLogin, so we've been trying to implement the new authWithOAuthPopup, but we keep getting a console error: TypeError: undefined is not a function.

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", ["firebase"]);

app.controller("appCtrl", function($scope, $firebase) {

var ref = new Firebase("https://[forge].firebaseio.com/users");

// Login using Google
$scope.loginGoogle = function() {
    console.log("Got into google login");
    ref.authWithOAuthPopup("google", function(error, authData) { 
        console.log("yeah, we got in! " + user.uid);
    }, {
          remember: "sessionOnly",
          scope: "email"
    });
};


 $scope.logout = function() {
    ref.unauth();
  };


});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The delegated authentication methods (i.e. authenticating via OAuth providers, or email / password, etc.) were added to Firebase core client libraries on October 3rd 2014, and will require a client library from that date or later (>= 1.1.0 for the web client).

Grab the latest web client library, and view the changelog, at https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/changelog.html.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to use the latest version of Firebase, otherwise it will not understand the ref.authWithOAuthPopup method

Here is the latest version: https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.0.2/firebase.js